# How to install Xcode 4.1 for Ruby developmnt

Tags: ruby, xcode, installation

How do I install gcc without 'LLVM'?

I would like to install an older copy of Xcode so that I can do Ruby development on Ruby 1.8.7.  This used to work on my machine before I upgraded from 4.1 to 4.3 via the app store. Once I upgraded I found that many gems would not compile. (TheRubyRacer, MySQL) I have since removed 4.1 and 4.3 from my system using the `sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all` command. After a reboot I verified that the `gcc` command failed and Xcode was not listed in the Applications folder.

I downloaded the Xcode 4.1 for Lion from the developer center and installed it. Unfortunitly I still fail to build the gems from before. I checked the version from gcc and I see I really have 4.2 installed.

`gcc --version` is

```
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

My error from `gem install mysql` is the following

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/jjasonclark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p358/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lm... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lz... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lsocket... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lnsl... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lmygcc... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/jjasonclark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p358/bin/ruby
    --with-mysql-config
    --without-mysql-config
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mlib
    --without-mlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-zlib
    --without-zlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-socketlib
    --without-socketlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-nsllib
    --without-nsllib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mygcclib
    --without-mygcclib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/jjasonclark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358/gems/mysql-2.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/jjasonclark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358/gems/mysql-2.8.1/ext/mysql_api/gem_make.out
```

Comment: can you check Preferences>Download do you have the command line tools installed?

Comment: I don't seem to have a `Download` option under Preferences in either the Xcode app or the Xcode installer app.  I could not run `gcc` until after the Xcode installer finished.

Comment: ok i was not sure what version it was introduced. basically when they moved Xcode into the apps directory you had to add command line tools after the fact. sorry for misleading you.

Comment: Understandable. From the developer center it looks like they last put out a command line tools pack for Xcode 4.1 was March 2012. Although the description of the pack says it is included in the full IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could never get Xcode to work with the older copy of Ruby. My solution was to install the [osx-gcc-installer](https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer).